# Database of atomic crystal structure data or images of rocks and minerals?

Tags: crystal-structure, reference-request, minerals, databases

I am looking for crystal structure images so I can redraw them in a nice form. However, I don't seem to find much searching Google.

[image]

Perhaps [this](https://opengeology.org/Mineralogy/13-crystal-structures/) is a slightly better example (searching for Quartz instead of Obsidian):

[image]

Is there a database or place which lists all rock / [mineral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minerals) crystal structures? I don't know what they are *supposed* to look like (I did organic chemistry but not advanced inorganic chemistry or geology), so knowing that the database/place has the expected crystal structures would be good to know. Also I'd be curious to know if they have any non-perfect crystal structure images, like things with impurities or crystal structure images of realistic rock compositions.

If not, wondering what major resource I should learn to figure out how to draw them on my own at scale (meaning, what major textbook or resource lists at least the crystal structures in text, if not having images or data which can be used to render images, and so the resource has hundreds or thousands of such pieces of data for efficiently drawing many of them).

Comment: I suggest [AMCSD](http://rruff.geo.arizona.edu/AMS/amcsd.php) for finding structures, and [VESTA](https://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/) for drawing. VESTA is free, available for all major desktop systems and comes with nicely written extensive manual. Frankly, currently the question is a bit too broad and not entirely clear: "*nice form*" leaves too much to imagination and is subjective.

Comment: Thank you. I am not asking about the "nice form" part, that is what I am going to do, I am just asking about where to find any images or data. Will take a look at these.

Comment: Here are a couple in 3D allowing for interactive exploration: https://virtual-museum.soils.wisc.edu/displays/